# No such file or directory found and not resolved inclusion

Tags: c++, eclipse

```
#include<Snap.h>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
     PNGraph Graph=TNGraph::New();
     Graph->AddNode(1);
     Graph->AddNode(2);
     Graph->AddEdge(1,2);
}


12:16:09 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project Graph ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IE:\\Snap-3.0\\snap-core" "-includeE:\\Snap-3.0\\snap-core" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o Graph.o "..\\Graph.cpp" 
cc1plus.exe: fatal error: E:\Snap-3.0\snap-core: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I want to add my `Snap.h` library I did all give the path library symbol and link path everything but got no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sanity check first: You do have a directory *E:\Snap-3.0\snap-core* and it does contain *Snap.h*?

With that out of the way, here’s your most likely culprit: `-includeE:\Snap-3.0\snap-core`. According to the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options):

> `-include file`
>
> Process file as if #include "file" appeared as the first line of the primary source file.

That’s probably not what you want. `-IE:\Snap-3.0\snap-core` is sufficient to add that directory to the include search paths.

Try removing the `-include` option from the command line and see if it works. I can’t tell you exactly how, though, since I’m not familiar with Eclipse.

--- Update following the comments ---

Compilation is working now, but the linker cannot find the library. This is usually a problem with how the `-L` and `-l` (lower case L) options are set. They can be a bit tricky to set up.

`-L` should point to the lib directory where your library is located. for Windows that’s where the `.a` files are.

`-l` specifies the name of the library with common pre-/suffixes removed: if you have `libsnap.a` the option should be `-lsnap`. You can also try the full path to a `.a` file.

If you have multiple `-l` options keep in mind that their order may be important.

Comment: Off course there is -lE: Snap-3.0\snap-core and off course there is Snap.h header and my GCC link has the same path as you give -lE: Snap-3.0\snap-core still not working thanks for your reply

Comment: i did what you said but now the problem came to here     13:47:02 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Graph ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-LE:\\Snap-3.0\\snap-core" -o Graph.exe Graph.o "-lE:\\Snap-3.0\\snap-core" 
C:/MingGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\Snap-3.0\snap-core
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately i had only header files no such library with extension .a or thinks like that i don't know what to do can you add this library to your eclipse or visual c++ plz your help can save my life    https://snap.stanford.edu/snap/download.html    download this library and try it in eclipse or visual studio

Comment: I don't had the Snap.so file i do have only Snap.h header file and Snap.cpp file

Comment: I neither use Eclipse nor Visual Studio. From a quick look at your link Snap doesn’t seem to provide binaries, so you’ll have to build it yourself. Instructions should be provided with the source download. Look for a README or INSTALL file or a "docs" (or similar) directory. The website might also have build instructions.

Comment: How to i built it i have no idea do you know something about it? any kind of help would be appreciated